# Sitecore 8.2: Why does the Rich Text editor wrap internal Sitecore-links in dual anchor-tags?

Tags: telerik, sitecore8

Case:

On a Sitecore **8.2 Update-2 rev. 161221** installation, when using the Rich Text Editor and the *Insert Sitecore Link* button to insert an internal link like this:

[image]

the html generated ends up wrapping the link in 1 too many anchor-tags, like this:

```xml
Test test <a><a href="~/link.aspx?_id=EA62777446C048E186B95D43115E22AA&amp;_z=z">Link</a></a>&nbsp;test&nbsp;Test test test
```

sometimes furthermore replacing the selected text when clicking the button with the text *"Link"* (removing the originally selected text completely). What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution - in short, remove the following code from the bottom of the file *~/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/RTEfixes.js* :

```js
(function () {
    if (!window.Telerik) return;
    var $T = Telerik.Web.UI;
    var Editor = $T.Editor;
    Editor.UnlinkCommand = function (editor, options) {
        var settings = {
            tag: "a",
            altTags: []
        };
        Editor.UnlinkCommand.initializeBase(this, [editor, settings, options]);
    };
    Editor.UnlinkCommand.prototype = {
        getState: function (wnd, editor, range) {
            var states = Editor.CommandStates;
            var result = Editor.UnlinkCommand.callBaseMethod(this, "getState", [wnd, editor, range]);
            return result === states.Off ? states.Disabled : states.Off;
        }
    };
    Editor.UnlinkCommand.registerClass("Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.UnlinkCommand", Editor.InlineCommand);
    Editor.UpdateCommandsArray.Unlink = new Editor.UnlinkCommand();
})();
```

What tipped me off was an attempt to upgrade to Sitecore 8.2 Update-5 rev. 170728 and look at the diffs. Here, the block above was removed. **However**, it also seemed that the *Telerik.Web.UI* package was bumped up from some **2014.1.403.45** version **2017.2.621.45** meaning, that I might have broken something.

Never really investigated more - looking at the javascript at a glance, it would seem that there was a fix for some "unlinking", that was rendered unnecessary when getting the Telerik-controls up to date. I tried adding some misc. links (internal + external) and removing them again using the *Remove Link* button from the ribbon, and it seemed to work just fine. If anyone can elaborate on what this fix might have been, please tell.

Also, if any Sitecore employee can explain why this apparent bug was never documented neither in "Known issues" for the Update-2 nor Release-notes for Update-3, -4 or -5, I'm all ears, as this could have saved us hours of debugging.

Comment: Did you ever encounter any issues from this? We're having the same issue and this seems to fix it, but I'm not sure what it actually does.